# How to link Cmake project in CXX Rust and use on Rust?

Tags: c++, rust, cmake, rust-cargo

I did this in cxx:

```
fn main() {
    cxx_build::bridge("src/main.rs")
        .file("src/something.cc")
        .flag_if_supported("-std=c++17")
        .compile("my_demo");
}
```

I want to link something.cc with another C++ library, but still run everything on Rust. I thus want to call C++ code, from Rust, and still have it compiled and linked using Cargo. [All the projects I find](https://cxx.rs/build/cmake.html) are the inverse: compiling rust from Cmake and using on C++.

So, how do I compile a cmake project from build.rs and link to something.cc?

Comment: Try the [cmake](https://crates.io/crates/cmake) crate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cxx`](https://crates.io/crates/cxx) can work with Cargo and C++ build systems. [`autocxx`](https://crates.io/crates/autocxx) might also be useful.

Comment: How does cxx invoke Cmake? I couldn't find this option